# htaccess redirect and rewrite rules conflicting

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want to rewrite all requests to index.php?r=
So that /sth becomes /index.php?r=sth

I have applied this rule that works:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.*\.(jpg|css|js|gif|png|pdf|php)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?r=$1 [L]
```

However I want to also have redirects such as

```
Redirect 301 /sth /sth-new
```

What happens is that it works but the url becomes:

```
/sth-new?r=sth
```

Do you have any solutions - suggestions about why this is happening?
How can I implement a global rule and also have simple redirects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
RewriteRule ^sth/?$ /sth-new? [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(jpg|css|js|gif|png|pdf|php)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?r=$1 [L]
```

You should keep external redirect rules before your internal rewrite rules.

Comment: Thank you this works. I also have some external links that are like sth/?someparam=sth. This should redirect to /sth-new (no params). How can I implement this using the above rule?

Comment: Nope it didnt' work...
This is the exact example:
    #RewriteRule ^accident_service/?tab=1/?$ /accident-service/antikatastash-oxhmatos [R=301,L]

Comment: That is different URL from your earlier comment where you wanted to redirect `sth/?someparam=sth` to `/sth-new?`

Comment: Ι dont see the difference...
sth -> accident_service/ 
?someparam=sth -> ?tab=1 
/sth-new -> /accident-service/antikatastash-oxhmatos 
I hope it is clear now. Thank you anyway.

Comment: Of course there is a difference, you **cannot** match query string using `RewriteRule`. I have posted several answer addressing this.